# Typescript Commutative Mixin Composition

Tags: typescript

Say I have a base encoder class with method

```
encode(obj: {body: Uint8Array}): Uint8Array
```

and I extend it to accept different `obj.body` types with one / more mixins - i.e.:

```
function numberMixin(encoder) {
    return class extends encoder {
       encode(obj) {
           if (isNumberObj(obj)) {
              ...
              return super.encode(transformed);
           }
           return super.encode(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

and compose these mixins

```
const Encoder = etcMixin(numberMixin(stringMixin(Base)));
```

is there a way to annotate each mixin / encoder so that the resulting class's encode method knows which types it accepts?  I can specify input / output functionality but then mixin order is rigid and can't be extended easily.

One option is to use generic type parameters on each mixin, but then I have to specify the type at each step in the composition, which seems redundant / too verbose.

`numberMixin<U, T extends Constructor<IEncoder<U>>>(encoder: T): T & Constructor<IEncoder<Number|U>>;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the fact that an intersection of function types is treated the same as an overloaded function, so we can construct the type of encode as being `BaseClass['encode'] & newOverlaodSignature`.

The only wrinkle is that we can't use method syntax to do this, we need to use function field syntax, this means we will declare the fields, but assign it to the prototype manually. Also since we are adding the function manually we can't use the `super.` syntax we will need to manually call the base class implementation, so we lose some type safety there.

The good news is that the call site looks nice and that all the overloads are present:

**Edit**
Extra credit work from the comments, also collect the types so we can use them in other mixins. We can do this if we add an extra static property to the type which will contain a fields for each added type. The reason we need a field and not nust a field of the type is that the returned type will be `AddedStuff & T` so this will trickle down to the type field an we get an intersection of all defined `type` fields from all mixins. The `printEncodedMixin` uses the extra type info:

```
class EncoderBase {
    constructor(param: string) {

    }
    encode(obj: { body: Uint8Array }): Uint8Array {
        return obj.body;
    }
    static type: { Uint8Array: Uint8Array }
}
type EncoderType = {
    new (...args: any[]) : { encode: (obj: { body: Uint8Array }) => Uint8Array }
    type: any
}

function numberMixin<T extends EncoderType>(encoder: T) {
    function isNumberObj(obj: any): obj is { body: number } {
        return obj && typeof obj.body === 'number';
    }
    let resultClass = class extends encoder {
        encode!: InstanceType<T>['encode'] & ((obj: { body: number }) => Uint8Array);
        static type : { number : number }
    }
    resultClass.prototype.encode = function (obj: any) {
        if (isNumberObj(obj)) {
            return encoder.prototype.encode(obj);
        }
        return encoder.prototype.encode(obj);
    }

    return resultClass;
}

function stringMixin<T extends EncoderType>(encoder: T) {
    function isStringObj(obj: any): obj is { body: string } {
        return obj && typeof obj.body === 'string';
    }
    let resultClass = class extends encoder {
        encode!: InstanceType<T>['encode'] & ((obj: { body: string }) => Uint8Array);
        static type : { string : string }
    }
    resultClass.prototype.encode = function (obj: any) {
        if (isStringObj(obj)) {
            return encoder.prototype.encode(obj);
        }
        return encoder.prototype.encode(obj);
    }
    return resultClass;
}

function printEncodedMixin<T extends EncoderType>(encoder: T) {
    type Body<T> = T extends any ? {body : T} : never;
    return class extends encoder {
        printEncoded(b: Body<T['type'][keyof T['type']]>) {

        }
    }
}

const Encoder = printEncodedMixin(numberMixin(stringMixin(EncoderBase)));

let d = new Encoder(""); // ctor params still work
d.encode({ body: "" });
d.encode({ body: 0 });
d.encode({ body: {} }); // Error
d.printEncoded({ body: "" }) //  printEncoded({body: string;} | {body: number;} | {body: Uint8Array;}): void
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks for the help.  Can another mixin gather `encode`'s derived argument type as an argument type for a different method?  The generated code may stay exactly the same.  i.e. `printEncoded(obj: { body: number }|{ body: string }|{ body: Uint8Array }): void`.

Comment: @SamZagrobelny I'll have to think about it, but I'm pretty sure we can put something together that will do that. I'll get back to you tomorrow morning, it's bed time now :-)

Comment: Any other thoughts on this?  I've had no luck finding this pattern in typescript or any another language.

Comment: @SamZagrobelny Oh sorry, I forgot about it, but can't really do it right now. I'll add a reminder , scout's honor I'll get back to you tomorrow :D

Comment: Hey, no problem, thanks a lot for your input so far.

Comment: @SamZagrobelny Added to the answer.